# MySQL insert from a table assigning auto-increment ID and update FK in third table

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, last-insert-id

I have 3 tables

```
old_customers
id   name
 5   Mario
13   John
..   ...

new_customers
id   name   address
 7   Luigi  Roma
..   ...    ...

orders
id   customer_id
 1   5
 2   7
 3   13
..   ..
```

I want to copy `old_customers` to `new_customers` assigning them a new auto-increment id and updating the orders foreign key `customer_id`.
How to perform this simultaneous INSERT and UPDATE in one simple MySQL query?

A basic psudo-sql idea

```
INSERT INTO new_customers (name) SELECT name FROM old_customers
AND
UPDATE orders SET customer_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE customer_id=old_customers.id
```

---

A week later ...

Thanks to help received this is the developed MySQL solution:
create a PROCEDURE that declare a CURSOR and INSERT+UPDATE fetched results in a LOOP

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE move_costumers()
BEGIN
  DECLARE fetched_id INT(3);
  DECLARE fetched_name VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id,name FROM old_customers;

  OPEN my_cursor;  
  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN END; 
    LOOP
      FETCH my_cursor INTO fetched_id,fetched_name; 
      INSERT INTO new_customers (name) VALUES (fetched_name);
      UPDATE orders SET orders.customer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() 
        WHERE orders.customer_id = fetched_id;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  CLOSE my_cursor;
END//
```

It's a loop without control variable and without label, as I found in [Simple Cursor Traversal 2](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=186)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you write a [udf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html), it will help you achieve your requirement.

The procedure for this purpose will be something like this ::

Follow the steps ::

1)Get the largest id used in new_customer table eg.

```
(Select max(id) into v_curr_id from new_users group by user_id)
```

and store it in a variable as v_curr_id.
2) Create a cursor which iterates and reads every row of the old_customer and everytime store it into a variable v_old_cust_id, v_old_custname
3)Inside the cursor : 
 increment the v_curr_id and insert a new row in the new_cust table having the cust_id as v_curr_id and name as v_old_custname.
e.g.

```
insert into new_customers(id, name) values (v_curr_id,v_old_custname);
```

Then update the order_table like

```
 update order_table set cust_id = v_curr_id where cust_id=v_old_custname;
```

4) After creation you will just have to call the procedure
like

```
call my_proc()
```

For syntax reference, visit  [cursor_example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0240__Cursor/0060__Fetch.htm)

Comment: Sorry for my naive question, I'm really new in sql. I tried to use various approaches such as while, loop, trigger, create procedure... But with poor results.
 I am grateful for even a simple suggestion on what approach might work.

Comment: @Salvador No issues mate, I have edited my answer, hope this will help :-)

Comment: Sashi thank you very much for your suggestions! Sorry but I'm hesitant to set this as accepted answer because is a track very useful but incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

UDF? come on...

just copy old customer data into new_customer table, adding old_id as a column so you could update this way:

```
INSERT INTO new_customers (name,old_id) SELECT name, id FROM old_customers

UPDATE orders o
SET customer_id = (select id form new_customers nc where nc.old_id = o.id)
```

Proc with cursor will be soooo slow...